# Sharing Music files via WhatsApp on Lumia625

Tags: music, whatsapp, internet-sharing

How do you share audio files saved on your phone using WhatsApp. I use a Lumia 625, and have done everything possible to share music files saved on the phone. Is it possible to share media files saved on phone via WhatsApp, specific inquiry for music files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to share audio files through WhatsApp on Windows Phone.
You can share pictures, videos and contacts by pressing the paper Clip in the conversation view.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Now you can easily share audio file through WhatsApp in a Windows Phone. ALl you need to do is "update whatsapp".

WhatsApp has included the feature to send audio files without any tweaks.

Source: [How to send Music files/Songs through WhatsApp in Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/07/how-to-send-music-filessongs-through-WhatsApp-Windows-Phone.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can share audio files through whatsapp.

You need a file amanger like 'Files'. Go to the audio file location. Copy it and paste it in the media folder (like 'Camera roll'). Change the file extension to '.mp4' to make it look like a video file.

Go to whatsapp and attach video, now you can see your song file as a video. Just attach and press send. It'll be sent as an audio file.